# How to get ILO management IP and Mac address

Tags: hp-proliant

I am looking for a way to find the IP address of the HP Proliant server ilo.
I have searched a lot, but no luck. there are way to reboot and get into the bios for getting it. But i cant reboot the production server.

From the Linux server there are some tools I don't know which one to use.

from the below ilo prompt there must be some way to get the ip.

```
</>hpiLO->
```

The server is a under cloud env BM as a service. So I can login to both ilo and server only.

Comment: How did you get the ilo prompt in the first place?

Comment: It's configured with hostname. Ping is not working it's dropped.

Comment: you could look up the hostname of the ip address from the system you're connecting from, and ARP tables. Exact tools would depend on the OS.

Comment: If you have the hostname, you don't _need_ ping just to resolve that name to an address. (That always happens _before_ ping packets are sent, anyway.)

Comment: The question doesn't suppose the ILO has an IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use another approach - checking from the system you're connected on.

I have a Windows box in front of me so I'd use `nslookup` to look up the ip address for the hostname, then `arp` to look up the MAC address. (The latter assumes the two systems are in the same subnet, as MAC addresses are not visible through a router. Though you could of course check the ARP cache *of the router*.)

```
C:\Users\faile_000>nslookup phoebe
Server:  router.asus.com
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    phoebe
Address:  192.168.1.43


C:\Users\faile_000>arp -a 192.168.1.43

Interface: 192.168.1.110 --- 0x1b
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.1.43          c0-7c-d1-c0-39-44     dynamic
```

Likewise you can use `host` or `dig` to look up IP addresses on Linux, and `arp` or `ip neigh show` to see the ARP cache.

```
   [geek@phoebe ~]$ host clocacina
clocacina has address 192.168.1.10
^[[A[geek@phoebe ~]$ dig  clocacina

; <<>> DiG 9.10.4-P1-RedHat-9.10.4-1.P1.fc24 <<>> clocacina
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12329
;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;clocacina.                     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
clocacina.              0       IN      A       192.168.1.10

;; Query time: 54 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 13 16:37:04 SGT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43


[geek@phoebe ~]$ ip neigh show 192.168.1.10
192.168.1.10 dev bridge0 lladdr 00:16:d3:2d:8b:9a STALE
[geek@phoebe ~]$ arp 192.168.1.10
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
Clocacina                ether   00:16:d3:2d:8b:9a   C                     bridge0
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention some details, question edited.

Comment: You can still look up the IP address this way.

Comment: This only works when the ILO is already on the network. What if you need the MAC address to register the ILO in DHCP?

Comment: Trickier - you'd need *something* to start with - maybe unfortunately eyeball what the server says.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but hponcfg -w did not return a MAC for me.  I used the following:

ssh server-ilo "show -a" | grep MAC

or more specifically:

</>hpiLO->  show /map1/enetport1/lanendpt1

Properties
EnabledState=enabled
MACAddress=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Comment: This only works when the ILO is already on the network. What if you need the MAC address to register the ILO in DHCP?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
hponcfg -w iLO_ouput.out
```

You will get the general config from ILO.

Try this or a later Version:
https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=7252838&swItemId=MTX_ed2c3a30d95f49b8a0eda8e2af&swEnvOid=4184

Comment: This configuration doesn't contain a MAC address.